# Изменение атрибута по клику

Tags: javascript

Необходимо по клику менять картинку.
Т.Е. имеем

```
 <td><img src="img/play.png"></td>
```

меняется на

```
 <td><img src="img/stop.png"></td>
```

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Про все необходимые для этого действия и инструменты рассказывается в любом учебнике по js, с чем возникла проблема?

Comment: `var play = false, img = document.querySelector('img'); img.addEventListener('click', () => { img[0].src = play ? 'img/stop.png' : 'img/play.png'; play = !play; });`

Comment: попробуй так : `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ сюда вставь то что написал Медвед });` , только  это `img[0].src` замените на это : `img.src`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день. Попробуйте так, должно работать.

```js
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    
    function changeImg(elem){
        if(elem.src.indexOf('play.png') > 0){
            elem.src = 'img/stop.png';
        } else {
            elem.src = 'img/play.png';
        }
    }    
//});
```

```html
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
<tr>
<td><img src="img/play.png" onclick="changeImg(this);" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td><img src="img/stop.png" onclick="changeImg(this);" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: как Игорь Игорю скажу: не видна будет `changeImg` в `onclick` :(

Comment: @Igor Я Вам верю, опыта у Вас как видно больше. Я у себя проверил и все работает. Если не сложно, объясните, почему не будет работать?

Comment: попробуйте теперь щелкнуть на `img`: функция `changeImg` - локальная, видна только внутри анонимного обработчика, но не в глобальной области видимости

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Я уже тоже разобрался, даже не мог подумать, что так будет )) Получается, что в таком случае лучше делегировать обработку в table? И уже там смотреть, на какой элемент кликнут?

Comment: нет, просто закомментируйте две строчки

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Вот нашел случайно. То, что нужно. Одно НО - на странице несколько картинок таких (в списке  li). В таком случае, скрипт реагирует только на 1 картинку. А как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии img1 менялось на img2, при этом все остальные img2 на странице менялись на img1, кроме нажатой картинки. Суть понятна - обычная кнопка плей в плэйлисте.

Сам скрипт:

```
<script>
function chg(id){
if (document.getElementById(id).src.indexOf("img/play.png")>0){
document.getElementById(id).src="img/stop.png"
}else{
document.getElementById(id).src="img/play.png"
}
}
</script>
```

И в нужном месте:

```
 <img src="img/play.png" id="img_1" onClick="chg(this.id)">
```